# Can useState hook receive a callback as a parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am refactoring some typescript code and it looks like a mistake for me:

```
const [previousFormType, changePreviousFormType] = useState<string>(() => selectedFormType)
```

I am not sure if the code is working and why somebody would do it like this. I didn't find any spec which says the parameter can be a callback function
I would rather change it in:

```
const [previousFormType, changePreviousFormType] = useState(selectedFormType)
```

selectedFormType is a string

Answer (score 4):

A callback can be used to set the initial state if the initial state is the result of an expensive computation. See the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) for more information about it.

Both of your examples are equivalent, but in your case

```
const [previousFormType, changePreviousFormType] = useState(selectedFormType)
```

is a better choice.

Comment: But code above does not call `selectedFormType` but just return it. So I believe it's just a mistake rather lazy init by intention.

Comment: `() => selectedFormType` is called by react itself on the initial render; `previousFormType` will be a string if `selectedFormType` is a string. Not a mistake, but you really don't need to create a callback just to pass `selectedFormType` as initial value.